# Изменить текст по буквам C#

Tags: c#, текст

Я хочу сделать так чтобы при выведении ключа в label ключ менялся от оригинального, примеру оригинал `X4S0F-FA2SKL-JS28S` а в `Label` показывался в рандомных местах `@` тобишь `X4@@F-FA@@@L-JS@@@`

Помогите пожалуйста на C#

Comment: Ну разбейте строку в список отдельных символов. Потом замените какое-то кол-во символов, рандомно выбирая позицию для замены. И потом склейте обратно список в строку. Сами строки в `C#` иммутабельны, как и во многих других языках, напрямую в строке ничего поменять нельзя.